# Passing list of enum values as HTTP query parameters

Tags: java, list, http, get, query-string

I want to pass list of enum values as HTTP query parameter. The entry point of the server side looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/getMyResult")
public MyResultType getMyResult(@QueryParam("me") final List<MyEnum> myEnums)
```

This cannot be modified. Consider `MyEnum` contains values `MyValue1`, `MyValue2`, `MyValue3` and `MyValue4`. (`MyResultType` is not relevant for this question.) Passing only one value, as follows, works fine (which is a bit strange for me):

```
http://localhost/getMyResult?me=MyValue1
```

However, passing list of elements this way:

```
http://localhost/getMyResult?me=[MyValue1,MyValue3,MyValue4]
```

or this way:

```
http://localhost/getMyResult?me=MyValue1,MyValue3,MyValue4
```

or this way:

```
http://localhost/getMyResult?me=["MyValue1","MyValue3","MyValue4"]
```

does not work, it throws exception something like this (error message to the first option):

```
RESTEASY001720: Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.QueryParam(\"me\") [...]
No enum constant com.mycompany.myapp.MyEnum.[MyValue1,MyValue3,MyValue4]
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass a list of `MyEnum` elements as HTTP GET query parameter? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost/getMyResult?me=MyValue1&me=MyValue2&me=MyValue3` ?

Comment: You can send it using POST method, so in Java you'll have to modify the annotation only and don't use @QueryParam

Comment: @khelwood: thanks for the hint; that is the solution (as also proposed by Jordi Castilla)

Comment: @MaxG: thanks for your comment. Indeed, that is not an option for me, because I have read-only access to the Java server code, and I have full control on the client code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this (and other cases you need to pass a `List`) you must insert name of the parameter for each element.

In this way:

```
http://localhost/getMyResult?me=MyValue1&me=MyValue3&me=MyValue4
```

Comment: @CsabaFaragó glad to help! :)

Comment: @CsabaFaragó I haven't warned, but be careful with lenght of url. If your Enum can contain several values you can exceed the max length!

Comment: Thank you for your warning!